# Why doesn't Jest complete the async operation(s) in this Node test?

Tags: node.js, jestjs, knex.js

I have the following simple test setup:

```
test('what did I do to deserve this', async () => {
  expect.assertions(1)

  const data = await fetchData() // or fetchData2 
  expect(data).toBe('peanut butter')
})

async function fetchData () {
  return "peanut butter"
}

async function fetchData2 () {
  return knex.select('name').from('foos')
}
```

When I use `fetchData` jest finishes happily.
But when I use `fetchData2` it complains of this:

> Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.
>
> This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't
>   stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with
>   `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.

The data variable does have the result from the db query, and other callers higher in the API resolve the query fine and continue the execution of other statements.

I have tried:

1. the `--detectOpenHandles` flag but it doesn't show me anything.
2. making the expect pass for `fetchData2` in case it was [the issue described here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1873#issuecomment-275916518)
3. passing a `done` arg to the async function in `test`.  It does exist, but calling it does not fix the warning.
4. throwing try/catch blocks at it

Thanks for any help on making this happy.

Versions of things:

- Node v11.1.0
- "jest": "^23.6.0"
- "knex": "^0.15.2"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to call `knex.destroy()` in the end of the test suite to teardown connection pool.

Comment: Ahh, I see this ticket now https://github.com/Vincit/objection.js/issues/534.  Ty

Answer (score 19):

To forcefully close Jest rather than DB Connection :

```
--forceExit
```

So my test script looked something like this,

```
"scripts": {
        "test": "jest --forceExit"
    }
```

Comment: This works but now I'm seeing: "Force exiting Jest: Have you considered using `--detectOpenHandles` to detect async operations that kept running after all tests finished?"

Answer (score 0):

Got these errors:

1.

> A worker process has failed to exit gracefully and has been force
> exited. This is likely caused by tests leaking due to improper
> teardown. Try running with --detectOpenHandles to find leaks.

2. 

> Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.
>
> This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't
> stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with
> `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.
> node:internal/process/promises:246
> triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
> ^
>
> [UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing
> inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a
> promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with
> the reason "Error: Request failed with status code 404".] {   code:
> 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION' }
> ##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.

Example with global setup and teardown:

```
// setup.js
const knexConfiguration = require('../config/knex')[process.env.NODE_ENV];
const knex = require('knex');

const setup = async () => {
  const client = knex(knexConfiguration)
  await client.migrate.latest();
  await client.destroy();
};

module.exports = setup;

// teardown.js
const knexConfiguration = require('../config/knex')[process.env.NODE_ENV];
const knex = require('knex');

const teardown = async () => {
  const client = knex(knexConfiguration)
  await client.migrate.rollback();
  await client.destroy();
};

module.exports = teardown;
```

Source:

https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7287#issuecomment-510068325

Another example:

dbConnection.js

```
export default new Sequelize({...}); // The Sequelize instance.
```

some.spec.js

```
import dbConnection from './dbConnection';

const { SomeModel } = dbConnection.models;

describe('...', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
      await SomeModel.create({...});
  });
  ...
});

afterAll(async done => {
  // Closing the DB connection allows Jest to exit successfully.
  dbConnection.close();
  done();
});
```

https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7287#issuecomment-434058564