# Jest recommends using "--detectOpenHandles" which does nothing special

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest

I always get this message printed when I run my tests with `jest --silent`:

> Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.
>
> This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't
> stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with
> `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.

But when I run `jest --silent --detectOpenHandles`, nothing special happens, no extra message, no warning, nothing. It just completes correctly.

I am using:

```
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"jest-extended": "^0.11.5",
"jest-preset-angular": "^8.3.2",
"ts-jest": "^26.4.4",
"ts-mockito": "^2.6.1",
```

and my config is:

```js
const ignoredFiles = [
  '<rootDir>/src/test.ts',
  '<rootDir>/src/main.ts',
  '<rootDir>/src/jest-global.mocks.ts',
  '<rootDir>/src/polyfills.ts',
  '<rootDir>/src/test-helpers.ts',
  '<rootDir>/src/mocks',
  '<rootDir>/plugins/',
  '<rootDir>/coverage/',
  '<rootDir>/scripts/',
  '<rootDir>/android/',
  '<rootDir>/e2e/',
  '<rootDir>/ssd_hooks/',
  '<rootDir>/typings/',
  '<rootDir>/platforms/',
  '<rootDir>/plugins/',
  '<rootDir>/resources/',
  '<rootDir>/manual-plugins/'
];

module.exports = {
  preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/setupJest.ts'],
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!@ionic|@saninn|@ngrx|@capacitor-community)'],
  coverageReporters: process.env.CI ? ['text'] : ['lcov'],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', ...ignoredFiles],
  modulePathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/coverage/', '<rootDir>/plugins/'],
  collectCoverage: false,
  notify: true,
  coverageDirectory: './coverage',
  collectCoverageFrom: ['<rootDir>/src/**/*.ts', '!**/*.module.ts', '!**/*.enum.ts'],
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', 'package.json', ...ignoredFiles],
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      tsconfig: '<rootDir>/src/tsconfig.spec.json',
      diagnostics: {
        ignoreCodes: [
          6138, // declared but never read
          6133, // declared but never used,
          2322 // object should just have known keys
        ]
      }
    }
  }
};
```

How can I find what is causing Jest to show that warning?

Comment: I am running into the same issue. Did you find a solution or could you cern the cause?

Comment: Not really. Although it is not happening to me anymore

Comment: I am running into the same issue. Did you find a solution or could you cern the cause?

Comment: I never found out what was the problem.

Comment: would you be able to at least isolate your test file by running jest --silent --detectOpenHandles path/to/your/test-file.test.js ?
This would allow you to narrow the focus on specific test files

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at some Stack Overflow posts, and found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53266915/why-doesnt-jest-complete-the-async-operations-in-this-node-test) about this question.

I did some testing with the first answer and it works. Simply add:

```
// ... etc etc

"scripts": {
  "test": "jest --forceExit"
}

// ... etc etc
```

and that should fix your problem! Hope this works

Edit: supposedly it's a problem where Jest stays up when the database connection is shut off, so force quitting is the solution; this worked for me